# Problem with a function using realloc that seemingly worked 2 weeks ago

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault

So, a simple search function that's supposed to return a pointer to a array with indexes of elements that match x as well as keep count with another pointer - *count. Depending on compiler it just stop executing when I call this function or errors about realloc converting void to int and one of them gave me a segmentation fault as well... The most confusing part is I had very similar function on other project and it worked until today(I have proof in terms of screenshots that it did) and was not touched.

```
int *search(int arr[], int n, int x, int *count)
{
    int arrsize = 0;
    int *pointarr = malloc(sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < n -1; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == x)
        {
            arrsize++;
            pointarr = realloc(pointarr, sizeof(int) * arrsize);
            pointarr[arrsize - 1] = i;
        }
    }
    *count = arrsize;
    return pointarr;
}
```

I get that my pointer and memory allocation was never nice, but it worked... I'm lost.

```
int main()
{
    int x, n;
    int *tab; // it's later filled no problem as other, simpler function calls it with no problems
    int *tabindex;
    int *count = 0;  //I tried with both =0 and without
   
    //////

    tabindex = search(tab, n, x, count); //I tired with all stuff like &count *count etc etc if that's the problem but I don't think so
    for (int j = 0; j < *count; j++)
        printf("%d ", tabindex[j]);
```

Comment: `int *pointarr = malloc(sizeof(int));` --> `int *pointarr = NULL;`

Comment: "converting void to int" hmm... sure that is a correct quote?

Comment: `i < n -1` hmmm... why `-1` ?

Comment: To be strictly correct you shouldn't save the value returned by `realloc` in `pointarr` before checking for NULL. In any case you should check for NULL before `pointarr[arrsize - 1] = i;`. That said, I don't think that's the real problem here

Comment: That's just a relic from checking if I didn't try to access something I shouldn't it's not affecting the code right now, as it's without the -1 on my pc.

Comment: Well... you need to add info about the compilers used and exactly how you compile the code. Besides the minor hick ups mentioned above, the code is fine.

Comment: oh... you also need to shhow how the function is called... the function arguments may be invalid for the operations performed

Comment: I'm not 100% as I installed it long time ago for just one labs, but iirc I'm using gcc

Comment: You didn't include stdlib.h, did you?

Comment: stdlib.h is included. 
I'll edit the post in a sec to include the call

Comment: But... you write: "Depending on compiler..." so you must know the compilers used, right? I mean your claim is "It works with one compiler but fails with another" okay - fine - tell us which compilers you are using

Comment: That's more of a slip of a tounge, meant IDE and online "compilers" for a fast check if its not just visual code/computer problem

Comment: oh dear, oh dear... no memory for `count` in `main` That code has **never** worked. You simply dereference a NULL pointer. `count` must be an int and passed as `&count`

Comment: Ok... I'm genuinely underknowledged here. I fixed it and it's working fine. I didn't know you had to allocate to single variables as it seems my IDEs before did it for more or something... Forget you saw anything

Comment: `int *count = 0;` --> `int count;` and `search(tab, n, x, count);`--> `search(tab, n, x, &count);`

Comment: **Where** do you fill `tab`? In the code you show, you pass a `NULL` pointer and access it inside your function which is clearly UB.

Comment: No... your IDE never ever did it for you. Your code is and was wrong.

Comment: Well, it no longer is, big thank you, helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you compile the C code using C++ compiler. If you started to use Visual Studio (which is the most probable option), you need to change the project option to compile as **C** language.

[image]

Comment: I'm using visual studio code right now, and nothing similar comes back in setting, except that I have it set to C in the bottom right. I also didn't change anything and did not code in C++ since the last time same stuff worked

Comment: @keiji12 But the message is clear. What compiler are you using

Comment: I'm using gcc, I'm sorry as I'm not as good with this kind of stuff, I just installed it a while back along some extensions on studio code for one semester of labs and changed nothing afterwards